# JSON parsing and printing JSON object with variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I'm having trouble printing an object with a variable name.  It works when I hard code it.

```
            var objectVarName = "lat";
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(msg));

            // {"lat":"93"} is what JSON.stringify(msg) prints

            $('#display').prepend("<br/><br/>" + JSON.stringify(msg));

            //obj['lat'] works, obj[objectVarName] does not
            $('#display').prepend("<br/><br/>" + obj['lat']);
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/5LGVe/ Maybe your bug is elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that your variable name, casing, etc are correct...your code works if `msg` is a valid object, here's what I tested:

```
var msg = {"lat":"93"};
```

[You can test/see the result here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WVwab/), I changed [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) so the output is in order, no other changes besides that, the result is:

```
{"lat":"93"}
93
```